# Visual studio c# platformer,background issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, background

I am currently working on a platformer in C#,VS 2015
The problem i have encountered is:when i press the left/right arrow,the background moves behind the player in the opposite direction,and this happens using a timer(which cannot be set to a value lower than 1 milisecond).
Because the timer is limited to 1 milisecond,the background moves laggy,and i would like to solve this :D

Here is the code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Bitmap back;
    Bitmap bobright;
    Bitmap bobleft;
    Bitmap bobimage;
    Bitmap exit;
    Point boblocation = Point.Empty;
    Point exitlocation = Point.Empty;
    float offSet = 0, vit;
    int acc_secunde, acc_secunde_max = 30;
    bool left = false, right = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    public void Game()
    {
        int imageNumber = panel1.Width / back.Width + 3;
        using (Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(frame))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < imageNumber; i++)
                {
                    graph.DrawImage(back, offSet/2 % back.Width + i * back.Width - back.Width, 0);
                }
                graph.DrawImage(bobimage, boblocation);
                graph.DrawImage(exit,exitlocation);

            }
            using (Graphics graph = panel1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                graph.DrawImage(frame, Point.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        back = Properties.Resources.back;
        bobleft = Properties.Resources.bobleft;
        bobright = Properties.Resources.bobright;
        bobimage = bobright;
        exit = Properties.Resources.Exit;
        timer1.Start();

     }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        boblocation.X = panel1.Width / 2 - bobimage.Width / 2;
        boblocation.Y = 210;
        exitlocation.X = panel1.Width - exit.Width - 10;
        exitlocation.Y = 5;

        if (left)
        {
            offSet = offSet + acc_secunde;
            bobimage = bobleft;
        }
        if(right)
        {
            bobimage = bobright;
            offSet = offSet - acc_secunde;
        }
        Game();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            acceleratie.Start();
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            acceleratie.Start();
            right = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            acceleratie.Stop();
            deacceleratie.Start();
        }
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {

            acceleratie.Stop();
            deacceleratie.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void deacceleratie_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(acc_secunde > 0)
            acc_secunde = acc_secunde - acc_secunde_max / 3;
        if (acc_secunde <= 0)
        {
            deacceleratie.Stop();
            if (right == true)
                right = false;
            if (left == true)
                left = false;
            acc_secunde = 0;
        }
    }

    private void acceleratie_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if(acc_secunde< acc_secunde_max)
            acc_secunde+=2;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        if (mousePt.X > panel1.Width - exit.Width - 10 && mousePt.X < panel1.Width - 10 && mousePt.Y > panel1.Top + 10 && mousePt.Y < panel1.Top + 10 + exit.Height)
            Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _using a timer(which cannot be set to a value lower than 1 second)._ ` Huh?? Interval can be as low as 30(ms!). (It still won't look smooth as winforms can't easily be used for animation)

Comment: I was wrong,the timer is set to 1 ms,not second

Comment: No value less than around 20-30 ms will make a difference, at least not for the better.. There is no easy solution, as I said, Winforms is a poor platform for platformers or most other animations.

Comment: So you are saying there is no easy way of making the background scrolling less laggy?

Comment: Yes. Winforms is notoriously bad with animations as it can't (easily) synch the screen output with the screen refresh rate. Set the Interval to 25, make the background small and hope for the best. There are other tricks, but none I found to be convincing.